# Notions of derivative and integral in Banach spaces in Brezis' book

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, frechet-derivative

In chapter 7, page 184 of the book Functional analysis by Haim Brezis, the author gave a theorem of Cauchy, Lipchizt and Picard as follows:

**Theorem 7.3 (Cauchy, Lipchitz, Picard).** Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $F: E\rightarrow E$ be a Lipchitz map, i.e, there is a constant L such that $ \|Fu - Fv\| \leq L \| u -v \|, \forall u,v \in E.$ Then given any $u_0 \in E$, there exists a unique solution $u \in C^1([0,\infty), E)$ of the problem

\begin{equation}
       \begin{cases} \frac{du}{dt}(t) = Fu(t) \quad on \ [0,\infty), \\
                   u(0) = u_0.
       \end{cases}
\end{equation}

However, he did not give any definition of what is the derivative $\dot u(t) := \frac{du}{dt}(t)$ in the Banach space. Then, in the proof, he says that this is equivalent to the integral equation

$$ u(t) = u_0 + \int^t_0 F(u(s))ds. $$

I am fine with all the reasoning he gives in the proof but I don't know how to interpret the derivative and the integral above. What I have learned in some references is that the derivative of a path can be defined as

$$ \dot u(t) := \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{u(t+h)-u(t)}{h}, $$

provided the limit exists.

**Question 1:** Is this the correct spirit (the definition of derivative above) in this theorem?

For the integral $\int^t_0 F(u(s))ds$, a definition that I have leaned is Bochner integral. In this definition, we have to have a measure space (which in our case is $\mathbb{R}$) to construct integral of "simple functions" (taking finite values in Banach space) and then use completeness of $E$ to define the general integral. I would like to understand the sense of integral so my next question is

**Question 2:** Does Brezis implicitly mean it is in the sense of Bochner integral in this theorem? Or is it a different kind of integrals? Or perhaps do other kinds of integrals (which I don't know many) coincide in Banach spaces?

**Question 3:** When we differentiate the integral in the sense of the derivative above, does it give $F(u(t)$? (So the two operations are inverse of each other)

I'm amateur I don't know much about these "general" integrals in Banach spaces. I would hope to get a detailed explanation (and some references to read) if possible :(...

Thank you for your help, I hope I have put the context well enough :D.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes this is the correct spirit, you will encounter in these books many notation for the derivative, but for $U \in C^1 (I,E)$, you have
   $$u'(t) = \frac{du}{dt} (t) = \dot{u}(t)$$
   It only depends of the frame, for very abstract theorems it is often $u'$, when you want to specify the variable (other can be fixed) you use $\frac{d}{dt}$ and for physics and EDO, $\dot{u}$. But it also depends from the author...

For the integral, each one will, do the main interest is the fundamental analysis theorem that states if $f$ is continuous, there is an unique $F$ such that $F' = f$ and $F(0) = 0$ and it is $\int_0^x f(t) dt$. Just take Riemann's it is sufficient here since you function is very regular (they are all the same!).

2. I think it is not relevant to give more explanation.
3. Yes obviously with any integral you chose.

The Banach space condition is relevant when you study the proof, for example there is one with a fixed point theorem (Picard I think), the real version though is with $F(x,t)$ Lipschitz and $u'(t) = F(u(t),t)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a mild question, I know that Riemann integral can be defined in each interval like in the real case, but for Bochner integral, we only have the definition of $\int^\infty_0 f(t)dt$, where a sufficient ccondition for it's existence is $\int^\infty_0\| f(t) \|dt < \infty$ (which we might not have!). So if I want interpret it as Bochner, I have to define for each $x \geq 0$, the Bochner integral $\int^x_0 f(t)dt$, am I correct?

Comment: Bochner here is overkill, you should only consider your integral as a sort of inverse of the derivative. Here integrals are well defined on an interval, so no pb, it seems to be a pain in the ass to add the condition you are using. Think of it as a primitive rather than an integral since the $x$ moves

Comment: Can you detail a bit more on how to prove the existence and uniqueness of primitive rather than using an integral? I only know in the real case we have to use Riemann-Lebesgue integral...

Comment: If $F$ and $G$ verify the property, $(F-G)'=0$ thus $F-G$ is constant. Since $(F-G)(0) = 0$, $F-G = 0$ thus $F=G$. But to ensure existence, you need to construct the Riemann integral.

Comment: I think you mean $\| F(t)-G(t)\|$ is constant. I deduced that the map $ t \mapsto \|F(t)-G(t)\| $ is differentiable with 0 derivative, hence constant and used $F-G(0)= 0$ so $\|F(t) -G(t)\| = 0$, hence $F=G$. But with the hypothesis $H' = 0$ then we cannot say $H$ is constant I think.

Comment: No I meant that $F-G$ is constant since its derivative is zero, this is basic real analysis, thus $F-G= 0$

Comment: If you are not able to provide a proof of this theorem, I think you should consider mastering that first before Cauchy-Lipschitz-Picard and any other form of integrals, understanding the basics in depth is more important Thant searching for new theorems as quick as possible.

Comment: uhmm, F and G are functions that take values in general Banach space not $\mathbb R$....

Comment: Yes, the property is also valid for a Banach, try to show that if $f'$ is zero on a connected space, then it is constant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146694/discussion-between-jeffrey-jao-and-jules-besson).